# Фильтрация в БД Delphi 10

Tags: база-данных, delphi, фильтрация

Eсть БД (список фильмов) и нужно реализовать поиск по году выхода фильма (2020,2019,2016).
Через компоненты RadioButton .

Сама БД находится в DBGrid1 и подключена через ADOTable и DataSource.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне все таки кажется, что вопрос не про сортировку, а про фильтрацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для фильтрации по году можно использовать свойства `TADOTable.Filter` и `TADOTable.Filtered`. Эти свойства объявлены в классе `TDataSet`, синтаксис зависит от того как наследники (такие как `TADOTable`) их реализациют. Обычно это это SQL-подобный синтаксис.

```pascal
procedure TFormTest.RadioGroupYearClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOTable1.Filtered := False;
  ADOTable1.Filter := 'YEAR = ' + RadioGroupYear.Items[RadioGroupYear.ItemIndex];
  ADOTable1.Filtered := True;
end;
```